# Just events in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, events

While planning a project, I realized that it would run much better using evented programming. But it turns out that all the event libraries are focused on I/O stuff and don't give basic events like NodeJS' `EventEmitter` can, when another object inherits from it.

All that I am looking for is to enable ismple eventing in my C++ code. Let's assume this code as the example:

```
class Window : EventClass {
private:
    NativeWindow* _w;
public:
    Window() {
        // Initialize a window for the platform.
        _w = new NativeWindow();
        emit("init", _w);
    }
    void open() {
        // Open the window...
        emit("open", _w);
    }
    // ...
};

int main() {
    Window w();
    w.on("init", [](NativeWindow* w){
        cout << "Window initialized." << endl;
    });
    w.on("open", [](NativeWindow* w){
        w->setTitle("foo");
    });
}
```

Is there a library that would enable such behaviour? All the ones I saw were so focused on evented I/O, that they forgot to provide raw eventing itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs addons which allows you to use C++ libraries into nodejs. Refer this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

```
>> node-gyp configure build
```

This will create your addon, which is a C++ snippet and you can include it in your node js file using `require(\path\to\addon)`

Comment: I am aware of node-gyp and the recently published CMake.js. But I was actually looking for real C++ stuff, not an addon. Sure, I actually do extend my C++ addons with EE. `var cl = require("util").inherits(requrie("events").EventEmitter, myObj);` - but this is not what I am looking for in this case.